# Ajuda com Spinner - Android Studio

Tags: android, spinners

Olá,

Preciso fazer uma função que muda a imagem de um ImageView, de acordo com o que tiver selecionado em um spinner e com dados de entrada "altura" e "area".
Estou fazendo desse jeito e está dando bug quando eu clico para executar.

Agradeço a ajuda!

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_procedimentos);

    final Spinner categorias = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
     final ImageView tabela = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageTabelas);
     final EditText editArea = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editArea2);
     final  EditText editAltura = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editAltura);
    Button btExecutar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonExecutar);
    Button btVoltarInicio2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonVoltarInicio2);



    btExecutar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        private int contentView;

        public void onClick(View view) {

            Double area;
            Double altura;

            final Spinner categorias = null;

            if (editArea.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                area = 1.00;
            }
            else{
                area = Double.parseDouble(editArea.getText().toString().trim());
            }

            if (editAltura.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                altura = 1.00;
            }
            else{
                altura = Double.parseDouble(editAltura.getText().toString().trim());
            }


            categorias.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView <?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    ImageView tabela = null;



                    if(categorias.getSelectedItem().equals("Grupo A") && altura<750 && area<500{
                        tabela.setImageResource(R.drawable.teste);
                    }
                }
            });

        }});
```

Comment: Qual bug acorre?

Comment: vc está criando o spinner e o imageview novamente dentro do onclick do botão. usando os mesmos para efetuar onclick e setImage e eles estão nulos.